# How to write "gzip -c foo.txt > foo.txt.gz" with 2 redirection operators instead of 1

Tags: bash, redirect, gzip

A bit of an arbitrary question, but it's part of a school assignment so I don't really have a choice.

The problem in question is this:  compress foo.txt into foo.txt.gz while keeping the original file.

In addition, the answer needs to be in the form

```
[command] [redirection operator] foo.txt [redirection operator] foo.txt.gz.
```

I've already figured out (I think) the normal way to do this:

```
gzip -c foo.txt > foo.txt.gz
```

But it doesn't fit the required form.  Is there a way to get this to work with the redirection operator instead of -c or -k?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is actually a very simple answer.  All you do is switch the redirections.

```
gzip < foo.txt > foo.txt.gz
```

First, redirect the foo.txt into `gzip` then redirect the output to `foo.txt.gz` and the original file will remain.

Hope this helps!